# SQL Query with in Query returning more than one result

Tags: mysql, sql, coldfusion

I'm attempting to get the information from the `brews` and `recipes` tables based off of how many followers there are in table follow, but I am getting an sql error because I am returning more than one result in my query. Should I split this up in to two queries? Or is there as work around that would allow me to check for more than one `b.uid` in my outer `WHERE` statement

```
SELECT 
  b.bid AS bid, b.name AS bname, 
  r.name AS recipe, b.status AS status, 
  r.rid, a.f_name, a.l_name, a.pic_loc, a.uid AS uid
FROM 
  recipes r, brews b, account a
WHERE 
  b.uid = (SELECT followed FROM follow 
  WHERE follower = '#cookie.id#') 
  AND b.rid = r.rid AND b.uid = a.uid 
GROUP BY b.bid
ORDER BY b.time DESC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `WHERE b.uid IN (SELECT followed...`

Answer (score 0):

In order to return multiple result sets you need to use cfstoredproc, but that is not your issue here. Either change your "=" sign to an IN, in your where clause or change up your select to be a join. Your issue is just a bad query, not multiple result sets.

```
SELECT 
    b.bid AS bid, b.name AS bname, r.name AS recipe, 
    b.status AS status, r.rid, a.f_name, a.l_name, 
    a.pic_loc, a.uid AS uid
FROM 
    recipes AS r
    LEFT JOIN brews AS b
        ON b.rid = r.rid
    LEFT JOIN account AS a
        ON b.uid = a.uid
    LEFT JOIN follow AS f
        ON f.followed = b.uid
WHERE f.follower = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" value="#cookie.id#" />
GROUP BY b.bid
ORDER BY b.time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The GROUP BY clause is probably causing you problems as well. You should only have a GROUP BY clause in your query if you are using aggregate functions (SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), MAX(), etc...) and need to group the records you're totaling, etc. into subgroups.